How to add more space after prepended symbol in a table using siunitx in a tabularray?
My goal
I wanted to make a document with some bookkeeping tables. I figured having automatic summing etc. would be nice, so I resorted to the use of the spreadtab package. For colored rows etc. I needed tabularray and for formatting of the numbers inside the table I needed the siunitx package.
Question
I make use of table-space-text-pre = {€\,} with the \, to add some space before displaying the number, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. How come?
MWE
\documentclass{article}

% Unrelated packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% Related packages
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

% Setup of how numbers should be displayed
\sisetup{
    round-mode = places,
    round-precision = 2,
    round-pad = true
}

% Define command to display an amount
\newcommand{\EUR}[1]{%
    € \num{#1}%
}

% Define column type E to use in tables
% E[<width>]{<spacing>}
\NewColumnType{E}[2][1]{
    >{€\,}      % insert euro symbol before cell's element
    X[#1,       % column type that allows relative column widths
        r,      % always right horizontal alignment
        si = {  % use of siunitx library
            table-format = #2.2,            % spacing before and after decimal delimiter
            table-number-alignment = right, % horizontal alignment w.r.t. table
            table-space-text-pre = {€\,}    % make sure euro symbol is not part of spacing
                                            % TODO: why is the extra space not actually added for numbers
        }
    ]
}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}

\NewTblrEnviron{mytable}
\SetTblrInner[mytable]{
    row{1} = {
        guard,
        l, % left-align entire row
        font = \rmfamily\bfseries, % bold face
        bg = azure7, % blue background
        fg = white, % white foreground
        % TODO: how to remove euro symbol from first row?
    },
    row{Z} = {
        font = \rmfamily\bfseries % bold face
    }
}

\begin{center}
\begin{spreadtab}{{mytable}{
    width = 0.5\linewidth,
    colspec = {
        X[3]
        E[2]{1}
    },
    row{1} = {guard}, % Make sure the first row is not included in siunitx
}}
@ Items & @ Subtotal \\
@ Item 1 & 2 + 1/3 \\
@ Item 2 & 3 + 1/3 \\\hline
@ Total & sum(b2:b3) tag(total)
\end{spreadtab}
\STmakegtag{total}
\end{center}

The table shows \EUR{\STtag{total}} as the total.

\end{document}



I've noticed the same in another situation. Apparently \, gets ignored. If I do \NewDocumentCommand{\ts}{}{\,} and use \ts instead of \, I get the desired spacing.

Anyway, the EU regulations specify that € should go after the amount, separated by a thin space, except for Ireland, Malta and the Netherlands, where it's placed before the amount, with no space. And, in my opinion, you shoul have € just in the header and not repeat it in the body.

@egreg thanks for those insights! I'm from NL so that figures ;) I'll consider having € only in the header

With the standard settings, \, is ignored in a number as it 'looks like' a manually-inserted group separator. When you give e.g. K\, + 2.35, siunitx receives K\,2.35, which gets split into K (non-numeric) and \,2.35 (numeric) - then the \, is dropped. You can avoid that by setting
\sisetup{input-ignore = }

but of course you now can't have a hard-coded grouping. Or you can modify your input to hide the \, e.g.
\begin{tabular}{l| >{{K\,}}S[table-format={K\,}2.2]}

